# how i can include time from database to "Days ago code below"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code for days interval

```
<?php 
    $datetime1 = new DateTime(); // Today's Date/Time  
   $datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-07-17 15:30:17'); 
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
   echo $interval->format('%D days %H hours %I minutes ago'); 
?>
```

How can I include time from database
example

```php
<?php echo htmlentities($row['date']); ?>
```

Comment: Assuming you get an epoch time back from the database, you use that to create a PHP date of some sort: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13477788/1531971

Comment: What type of column is `date`? If you get a string of `2017-08-29 17:25:10` back, then you can just do `$datetime2 = new DateTime($row['date']);`.

Comment: Also, probably reference this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago

Comment: @Qirel the column in date is 2017/08/29

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using PHP, but if you want this on the front end you could consider moment.js: https://momentjs.com/ it handles human-like date outputs.''

Edit: after further searching, this is exactly what you're looking for momentPHP: https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php

Comment: can you tell me how  i can use the java script

Comment: You wouldn't have to - I found the same thing in php. Find the Edit