# How to make Php Timestamp Function For My zone

Tags: php

i am trying to make php timestamp function i make it like this

My code example

```
$t=time(); 
echo($t . "<br>"); 
echo(date("Y-m-d",$t));
```

but i want php timestamp in this format

> Saturday, August 18, 2018 10:55:34 AM GMT+05:30

```
output:-1534569934
```

what i need to changes in my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Epoch Time to Date PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477788/convert-epoch-time-to-date-php)

Comment: Set time zone `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/karachi");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tried,

```
<?php
$t = time(); 
echo(date("l, M d, Y h:i:s A",$t).' GMT '.date("O",$t));
```

I hope this solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to :

> i want php timestamp in this format
>
> Saturday, August 18, 2018 10:55:34 AM GMT+05:30

you can format your timestamp as this:

```
date('l ,F d,  Y h:i:s A \G\M\T P');
```

you also said :

> i am trying to make php timestamp function

First ,i don't see any function declaration nor return statement so you didn't try to make a function.However according to the format above and the fact that you want a custom timestamp function, you can build it this way:

```
function custom_timestamp(){
    return date('l,F d,Y h:i:s A \G\M\T P');
}
```

Then you can use it anywhere as timestamp and based on your own logic.

Comment: you can use`strtotime()`

Comment: But won't `strtotime()` convert it to something like this: 1534573764

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
    $timestamp=time();
    echo(date("F d, Y h:i:s A", $timestamp));
?>
```